# Uncaught ReferenceError when accessing an object from another JS file

Tags: javascript

I have various JS libraries in my web application, which are loaded before my main JS file (main.js). One of these libraries is [jshashtable](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/), but when I try to create a new Hashtable object in main.js, Google Chrome and Firefox throw a ReferenceError, complaining that the variable does not exist.

Here is the <head> of the application:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javacsript" src="/static/jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/main.js"></script>
```

Here is the problem line in main.js:

```
posts = new Hashtable();
```

This line is inside a function called `init` which is called when the page has finished loading (using the jquery $(document).ready() function).

Any reason why Hashtable is not global? Google maps and jquery objects work with no such problem. The source of jshashtable can be seen on [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable/source/browse/trunk/hashtable.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**: The problem is that you've got a typo in the `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javacsript" src="/static/jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>
<!--                   ^^---- here (the letters are transposed)       -->
```

I couldn't understand why you would be running into a problem and decided to actually copy-and-paste your script tags and replicate the structure exactly on my machine. And things stopped working and my world tilted 3° counter-clockwise until I finally stared at them long enough to see it.

<s>Provided that the jshashtable code really is at `/static/jshashtable-2.1.js` and your server is serving it up correctly (double-check on Chrome's resources tab in the dev tools), I can't see any reason for that. Your scripts are in the right order, and `jshashtable`'s docs show using a global `Hashtable` (and the code link you gave clearly shows it creating one).</s>

---

**Edit**: I've just replicated that same structure (same scripts, same order, using `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... });`) on my own server, and am not having that problem. I can create a `Hashtable` and use its functions.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4.4.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jshashtable-2.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My `main.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        var ht = new Hashtable();
        display("typeof ht = " + typeof ht);
        display("ht.size() = " + ht.size());
    }
    catch (e) {
        display("Exception: " + e);
    }

    function display(msg)
    {
        $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
    }
});
```

Only difference is I'm not using a `/static` prefix, and I'm absolutely certain that makes no difference.

Comment: I have verified that the jshashtable script is loading properly; the code shows up in dev tools with no errors.

Comment: @James: Very strange. I've replicated the structure (just edited my answer) and am not seeing the behavior you're describing. Unless something is actively clearing `Hashtable`, I can't see why it happens to you.

Comment: @James: Found it. I actually copied and pasted your `script` tags and things stopped working. Ultimately found the typo. Updated.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you - I thought I was missing something simple.

Comment: @James: No worries, we both were. Note to self: If the path looks right, and I even see the script load in Resources, check the `type` attribute. :-) BTW: You can drop the `type` entirely. Every browser on the planet defaults to JavaScript, and it's now even the *official* default as of HTML5. Best,

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I'm not sure I'd drop the the `type` attribute just yet, at least not until all the big browsers have at least minimal support for some of the perpetually moving target that is HTML5.

Comment: @Tim: All the big browsers *already* default to JavaScript for `script` tags, and always have as far as I know. (Try http://jsbin.com/itosi5 on any browser you can find.) HTML5 is (in this case) doing that thing it does (which is mostly good) of just codifying what's already in place. Re: moving target. Yeah, insane isn't it? And Hickson (the editor) thinks it's a good thing and has pretty much gone official with it. I guess we have to take the bad with the good. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Well, I know that omitting the `type` attribute *works* in all the main browsers, but doing so is only valid in HTML5, meaning you have to use an HTML5 doctype if you want your HTML to validate. Having done a little reading now, this seems to be relatively safe. Re. the spec, I can see Hixie's predicament: that spec wouldn't have been finished for years, but I don't really understand what use a spec that changes is. Sounds like an oxymoron to me.

Comment: @Tim: *"Sounds like an oxymoron to me."* And me, and my good friend who's also a professional software engineer. How are we supposed to hold browser vendors to account for not supporting X if X is a moving target? But Hickson has closer contact with vendors that I do, and in any case, there's little I can do about it. :-) So I have to hope he knows what he's doing a bit better now than (say) when doing the horror of the CSS2 spec. ;-)